# How can i get the first element from a sprite group in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I create the sprite group land. For that, i use the class Landschaft and the while loop
How can i get from first sprite in the sprite group land rect.x , rect.y rect.w and rect.h ?

> ```py
> class Landschaft(pygame.sprite.Sprite):       
>     def __init__(self,image):
>         pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) 
>         self.image = image 
>         #self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image )
>         self.rect = self.image.get_rect()        
>         #pygame.draw.ellipse(self.image, red, [self.rect.x,self.rect.y,self.rect.width,self.rect.height],3)        
>         x=random.randrange(0, breite -60) 
>         y=random.randrange(200, hoehe - 200) 
>         self.rect.center = (x,y) 
>
> land = pygame.sprite.Group()
>
> while len(land) < anzahl_gegenstaende:
>         ii = len(land)
>         img = pygame.image.load(f"Bilder/Gegenstaende/geg{ii}.png") 
>         if ii == 0:
>             img = pygame.transform.scale(img,(breite)) 
>         else:    
>             zb,zh = img.get_rect().size
>             scale_hoehe =100
>             scale_breite = int(100 * zb / zh)          
>             #img = img.convert_alpha() 
>             img = pygame.transform.scale(img,(scale_breite,scale_hoehe))            
>         m = Landschaft(img) 
>       
>         if not pygame.sprite.spritecollide(m, land, False):
>             land.add(m)
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list of sprites from a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) can be obtained with the [`sprites()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.sprites) method:. Therefore the first sprite in the *Group* is:

```py
first_sprite = group.sprites()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem?**
Your `land = pygame.sprite.Group()` prevents you from getting the first element from a sprite group in pygame. This is a fairly common problem. To get it you have to use `sprites()` as you did, but in a different way. You approached the solution with your code. You came close.

You have to write, as a solution to your problem, `group.sprites()` (with [0]) (not `pygame.sprite.Group ()`) to get from first sprite in the sprite group land rect.x, rect.y rect.w and rect.h

**Solution?**
The solution to your problem is:

```
class Landschaft(pygame.sprite.Sprite):       
    def __init__(self,image):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) 
        self.image = image 
        #self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image )
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()        
        #pygame.draw.ellipse(self.image, red, [self.rect.x,self.rect.y,self.rect.width,self.rect.height],3)        
        x=random.randrange(0, breite -60) 
        y=random.randrange(200, hoehe - 200) 
        self.rect.center = (x,y) 

land = group.sprites()[0]

while len(land) < anzahl_gegenstaende:
        ii = len(land)
        img = pygame.image.load(f"Bilder/Gegenstaende/geg{ii}.png") 
        if ii == 0:
            img = pygame.transform.scale(img,(breite)) 
        else:    
            zb,zh = img.get_rect().size
            scale_hoehe =100
            scale_breite = int(100 * zb / zh)          
            #img = img.convert_alpha() 
            img = pygame.transform.scale(img,(scale_breite,scale_hoehe))            
        m = Landschaft(img) 
      
        if not pygame.sprite.spritecollide(m, land, False):
            land.add(m)
```